# Angular unit testing Error: Expected spy getDateFormat to have been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to unit testing and hope someone help me.
I have a angular component called StudentComponent and it has following.

```
    public getAllStudents(){    
        this.apollo.query({
            query: GETALL_STUDENTS,
        }).subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.students = result?.data?.getAllStudents;
            this.students.forEach(element => {
            element.Age = this.CalculateAge(element.DateOfBirth);
            element.DateOfBirthString = this.getDateFormat(element.DateOfBirth);
            });
        });
    }

    public CalculateAge(dateOfBirth: any): number {
        let age = 0;
        if (dateOfBirth) {
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(dateOfBirth).getTime());
            age = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24) / 365.25);
        }
        return age;
    }

    getDateFormat(date: Date): string{
        let dateString = ""
        if(date){
            dateString = formatDate(date, 'yyyy/MM/dd','en_US').toString();
        }
        return dateString;
    }
```

I wrote the test case like following

```
    describe('getAllStudents', () => {
        it('makes expected calls', () => {
          spyOn(component, 'getDateFormat').and.callThrough();
          spyOn(component, 'CalculateAge').and.callThrough();
          spyOn(apollo, 'query').and.callThrough();
          component.getAllStudents();
          expect(apollo.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(component.getDateFormat).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(component.CalculateAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
  
        });
      });
```

this gave me an error. 'Expected spy getDateFormat to have been called.' Could anyone please guide me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getAllStudents` includes asynchronous code. With `Observable.subscribe`, your code will receive a delayed notification of the available `result`, most probably after `expect` has been evaluated.

There exist different ways to test asynchronous code with `Jasmine` (see [Asynchronous Work](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) from Jasmine documentation).

`Angular` also provides functionality to test asynchronous code. You can for example  execute your unit test in the [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone. Then, you need to invoke [`tick()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) just after calling `getAllStudents()`. This could look as follows:

```
it('makes expected calls', fakeAsync(() => {

  // given
  spyOn(component, 'getDateFormat').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(component, 'CalculateAge').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(apollo, 'query').and.callThrough();

  // when
  component.getAllStudents();
  tick();

  // then
  expect(apollo.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.getDateFormat).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.CalculateAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

> Please note that you're testing the implementation but not the result of the method. It would make more sense to consider the method `getAllStudents()` as a black box and check that `Age` and `DateOfBirthString` on all `students` are set as expected.